# Delete repeated results from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, rows

A MySQL query retrieves:

```
totalpoints --  name 
55 -- John Doe
55 -- John Doe
55 -- John Doe
55 -- John Doe
55 -- John Doe
21 -- Jean London
21 -- Jean London
13 -- Mark Derry
13 -- Mark Derry
13 -- Mark Derry
13 -- Mark Derry
4 -- Lara Croft
1 -- Ryan Mirtle
1 -- Ryan Mirtle
1 -- Ryan Mirtle
```

I need to show in a php page just:

```
totalpoints --  name 
55 -- John Doe
21 -- Jean London
13 -- Mark Derry
4 -- Lara Croft
1 -- Ryan Mirtle
```

How can I get rid off the repeated results? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using DISTINCT?
Seems pretty easy...
But you actually tried to google it? ou would have found it in no time.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Too new to mysql :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,totalpoints
from table
group by name
order by totalpoints desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct name,totalpoints from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy. use following query:

```
SELECT totalpoints, name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY totalpoints DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use DISTINCT keyword in your query to avoid duplicate entries